# WorkflowName field is null under task list

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow, task-list, workflow-tasks-list

I have created a list workflow from SPD and assigned a task to the approvers group. The workflow is triggering fine but when i want to fetch some of the columns like WorkflowName is coming with blank.
I also verified the Json response from REST API to check values are coming or not? But i found some of the properties are null.

Please some one help me how to fetch these details.

the below is my Json response from the WOrkflow Task list.

API: /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Workflow Tasks')/items

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "f63099fa-d207-4392-ad0d-384b11f4e967",
                    "uri": "http://inhydvmrstpr02:8080/Iow/_api/Web/Lists(guid'eba6894b-9f6c-4435-86fe-de728ac5a9a3')/Items(46)",
                    "etag": "\"2\"",
                    "type": "SP.Data.WorkflowTasksItem"
                },
                "FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "http://inhydvmrstpr02:8080/Iow/_api/Web/Lists(guid'eba6894b-9f6c-4435-86fe-de728ac5a9a3')/Items(46)/FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject"
                    }
                },
                "RoleAssignments": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "http://inhydvmrstpr02:8080/Iow/_api/Web/Lists(guid'eba6894b-9f6c-4435-86fe-de728ac5a9a3')/Items(46)/RoleAssignments"
                    }
                },
                "AttachmentFiles": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "http://inhydvmrstpr02:8080/Iow/_api/Web/Lists(guid'eba6894b-9f6c-4435-86fe-de728ac5a9a3')/Items(46)/AttachmentFiles"
                    }
                },
                "ContentType": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "http://inhydvmrstpr02:8080/Iow/_api/Web/Lists(guid'eba6894b-9f6c-4435-86fe-de728ac5a9a3')/Items(46)/ContentType"
                    }
                },
                "GetDlpPolicyTip": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "http://inhydvmrstpr02:8080/Iow/_api/Web/Lists(guid'eba6894b-9f6c-4435-86fe-de728ac5a9a3')/Items(46)/GetDlpPolicyTip"
                    }
                },
                "FieldValuesAsHtml": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "http://inhydvmrstpr02:8080/Iow/_api/Web/Lists(guid'eba6894b-9f6c-4435-86fe-de728ac5a9a3')/Items(46)/FieldValuesAsHtml"
                    }
                },
                "FieldValuesAsText": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "http://inhydvmrstpr02:8080/Iow/_api/Web/Lists(guid'eba6894b-9f6c-4435-86fe-de728ac5a9a3')/Items(46)/FieldValuesAsText"
                    }
                },
                "FieldValuesForEdit": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "http://inhydvmrstpr02:8080/Iow/_api/Web/Lists(guid'eba6894b-9f6c-4435-86fe-de728ac5a9a3')/Items(46)/FieldValuesForEdit"
                    }
                },
                "File": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "http://inhydvmrstpr02:8080/Iow/_api/Web/Lists(guid'eba6894b-9f6c-4435-86fe-de728ac5a9a3')/Items(46)/File"
                    }
                },
                "Folder": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "http://inhydvmrstpr02:8080/Iow/_api/Web/Lists(guid'eba6894b-9f6c-4435-86fe-de728ac5a9a3')/Items(46)/Folder"
                    }
                },
                "ParentList": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": "http://inhydvmrstpr02:8080/Iow/_api/Web/Lists(guid'eba6894b-9f6c-4435-86fe-de728ac5a9a3')/Items(46)/ParentList"
                    }
                },
                "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
                "Id": 46,
                "ContentTypeId": "0x0108003365C4474CAE8C42BCE396314E88E51F004B3581A3A187724E91023106EE3BD022",
                "Title": "Test task from R47",
                "PredecessorsId": {
                    "__metadata": {
                        "type": "Collection(Edm.Int32)"
                    },
                    "results": []
                },
                "Priority": "(2) Normal",
                "Status": "Not Started",
                "PercentComplete": null,
                "AssignedToId": 2,
                "TaskGroupId": null,
                "Body": "sfvhvsdf",
                "StartDate": "2020-10-30T09:32:23Z",
                "DueDate": "2020-10-30T01:00:00Z",
                "RelatedItems": "[{\"ItemId\":23,\"WebId\":\"0d2584b8-e9b0-4fb5-8590-b39d5cd52e34\",\"ListId\":\"8cbcc7fc-f045-4e88-88ac-a9dc0ac29085\"}]",
                "WorkflowLink": null,
                "OffsiteParticipant": null,
                "OffsiteParticipantReason": null,
                "WorkflowOutcome": null,
                "WorkflowName": null,
                "GUID": "9d48ca07-93f9-44a3-a277-74b0b9720744",
                "TaskOutcome": null,
                "ID": 46,
                "Modified": "2020-10-30T09:32:24Z",
                "Created": "2020-10-30T09:32:23Z",
                "AuthorId": 2,
                "EditorId": 2,
                "OData__UIVersionString": "2.0",
                "Attachments": false
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, this only works for workflow 2010. It would not show for workflow 2013.

You could create workflow 2010 instead to assign tasks.